# Webpack / PostCSS - OptimiseCssAssetsPlugin stopping CSS Sourcemap from being available in browser

Tags: css, webpack, source-maps, postcss

I am trying to use OptimiseCssAssetsPlugin within webpack, however when I introduce it, my css sourcemap, which appears to still be generated, is no longer available within chrome.

My webpack.config.js is the following

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
var precss       = require('precss');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var postcssImport = require('postcss-import');
var OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

  context: __dirname + '/frontend',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: "./index.js",
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, './static')
},
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      },
      {
        test:   /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', '!css-loader?sourceMap&importLoaders=1!postcss-loader')
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("si-styles.css"),
    new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin()
  ],
   postcss: function(webpack) {
        return [
            postcssImport({ addDependencyTo: webpack }), // Must be first item in list
            precss,
            autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions']  })
        ];
    },

}
```

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems to be something to do with either cssnano or postcss settings. I haven't found a solution either, this GitHub issue is the closest I've found: https://github.com/ben-eb/cssnano/issues/302